# Express a (1,1)-tensor field in another set of coordinates

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, differential-geometry

Let $M = \Bbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ be the extended complex plane and $F_1, F_2$ be charts<sup>1</sup> defined by $$F_1: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{C}, \quad F_1(x,y) = x  + iy$$ 
and
 $$F_2: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{C}\backslash\{0\} \cup \{\infty\}, \quad  F_2(u,v) = \frac{1}{u + iv}.$$

Let $$\omega = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \, dx \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$ I would like to express $\omega$ in $(u,v)$-coordinates and please verify my computations, thanks!

<sup><sup>1</sup> Convention issue: while most references define chart as a map $\varphi: O \subseteq M \to  U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$, the lecture notes define chart as the inverse of the aforementioned one.</sup>

---

Attempt: The transition map is $(x(u,v),y(u,v)) = F_1^{-1} \circ F_2(u,v)= F_1^{-1}(\frac{u - iv}{u^2 + v^2}) = (\frac{u}{u^2 +v^2}, \frac{-v}{u^2 +v^2})$. Then $x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2}$ and $e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} = e^{\frac{-1}{u^2 + v^2}}$.

On the other hand, $dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} = (\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^k} du^k ) \otimes ( \frac{\partial u^l}{\partial x^j}  \frac{\partial}{\partial u^l})=  \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^k}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial x^j}  du^k  \otimes  \frac{\partial}{\partial u^l}$. So $dx \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial u^k}\frac{\partial u^l}{\partial x^2} du^k  \otimes  \frac{\partial}{\partial u^l} = C_k^l du^k  \otimes  \frac{\partial}{\partial u^l}$.

But the Jacobian matrices are

\begin{align*}A = \bigg[\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^j}\bigg] &= \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}\begin{bmatrix}
u^2 + v^2 - 2u^2 &  -(-2uv) \\
-2uv&  - (u^2 + v^2 - 2v^2)\end{bmatrix}\\ & = \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}\begin{bmatrix}
 v^2 - u^2 &  2uv \\
-2uv&  v^2 -u^2\end{bmatrix} \\
B = \bigg[\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^j}\bigg] &= \bigg[\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^j}\bigg]^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 v^2 - u^2 &  -2uv \\
2uv&  v^2 -u^2\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Again, since $C_k^l = A^1_k B^l_2$,
\begin{align*}
C_1^1 =A^1_1 B^1_2  & = \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}(v^2 - u^2)(-2uv)\\
C_1^2 =A^1_1 B^2_2  & = \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}(v^2 - u^2)(v^2 - u^2)\\
C_2^1 =A^1_2 B^1_2  & = \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}(2uv)(-2uv)\\
C_2^2 =A^1_2 B^2_2  & = \frac{1}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}(2uv)(v^2 - u^2)
\end{align*}
So
$$\omega = \frac{e^{\frac{-1}{u^2 + v^2}}}{(u^2 + v^2)^2}[2uv(u^2 - v^2) du \otimes \frac{\partial }{\partial u} + (u^2 - v^2)^2 du \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial v} - 4u^2 v^2dv \otimes \frac{\partial }{\partial u}  - 2uv(u^2 - v^2) dv \otimes \frac{\partial }{\partial v} ]$$